SwiftData - Cannot use staged migration with an unknown coordinator model version
I'm having trouble with my first migration using SwiftData - it's pretty simple, just adding a new var into the class.
Here's the v1 model:
import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model
final class UnitSize_v1 {
    var unitName: String
    @Attribute(originalName: "size") var unitSize: Int
    var cost: Int
    var gameSystem: String
    
    init(unitName: String, unitSize: Int, cost: Int, gameSystem: String) {
        self.unitName = unitName
        self.unitSize = unitSize
        self.cost = cost
        self.gameSystem = gameSystem
    }
    
    static let sampleData = [
        UnitSize_v1(unitName: "Allarus Custodians", unitSize: 2, cost: 130, gameSystem: "40k"),
        UnitSize_v1(unitName: "Allarus Custodians", unitSize: 3, cost: 195, gameSystem: "40k"),
        UnitSize_v1(unitName: "Allarus Custodians", unitSize: 5, cost: 325, gameSystem: "40k"),
        UnitSize_v1(unitName: "Allarus Custodians", unitSize: 6, cost: 390, gameSystem: "40k"),
        UnitSize_v1(unitName: "Custodian Guard", unitSize: 4, cost: 180, gameSystem: "40k"),
        UnitSize_v1(unitName: "Custodian Guard", unitSize: 5, cost: 225, gameSystem: "40k"),
        UnitSize_v1(unitName: "Anathema Psykana Rhino", unitSize: 4, cost: 390, gameSystem: "40k"),
        UnitSize_v1(unitName: "Shield-Captain", unitSize: 1, cost: 140, gameSystem: "40k"),
    ]
}

and the v2 Model
//
//  UnitSize_v2.swift
//  Muster
//
//  Created by Douglas Idle on 29/09/2024.
//

import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model
final class UnitSize_v2 {
    var unitName: String
    @Attribute(originalName: "size") var unitSize: Int
    var cost: Int
    var allyCost: Int
    var gameSystem: String
    
    init(unitName: String, unitSize: Int, cost: Int, allyCost: Int, gameSystem: String) {
        self.unitName = unitName
        self.unitSize = unitSize
        self.cost = cost
        self.allyCost = allyCost
        self.gameSystem = gameSystem
    }
    
    static let sampleData = [
        UnitSize_v2(unitName: "Allarus Custodians", unitSize: 2, cost: 130, allyCost: 130, gameSystem: "40k"),
        UnitSize_v2(unitName: "Allarus Custodians", unitSize: 3, cost: 195, allyCost: 195, gameSystem: "40k"),
        UnitSize_v2(unitName: "Allarus Custodians", unitSize: 5, cost: 325, allyCost: 325, gameSystem: "40k"),
        UnitSize_v2(unitName: "Allarus Custodians", unitSize: 6, cost: 390, allyCost: 390, gameSystem: "40k"),
        UnitSize_v2(unitName: "Custodian Guard", unitSize: 4, cost: 180, allyCost: 180, gameSystem: "40k"),
        UnitSize_v2(unitName: "Custodian Guard", unitSize: 5, cost: 225, allyCost: 225, gameSystem: "40k"),
        UnitSize_v2(unitName: "Anathema Psykana Rhino", unitSize: 4, cost: 390, allyCost: 390, gameSystem: "40k"),
        UnitSize_v2(unitName: "Shield-Captain", unitSize: 1, cost: 140, allyCost: 140, gameSystem: "40k"),
    ]
}

Here are the definitions for v1 and v2 of the schema
import Foundation
import SwiftData

enum MusterSchemaV1: VersionedSchema {
    static var models: [any PersistentModel.Type] {
        [
            FactionFile.self,
            Categories.self,
            Faction.self,
            GameSystem.self,
            Ally.self,
            Detachment.self,
            Enhancement.self,
            ArmyUnit.self,
            ArmyList.self,
            UnitSize_v1.self,
            UnitComposition.self,
            IncludedUnit.self,
            Models.self,
            Loadout.self,
            BaseLoadout.self,
            Ability.self,
            Equipment.self,
            LoadoutLabel.self,
            AddModels.self,
            AltModels.self,
            Subfaction.self,
            WeaponAdd.self,
            WeaponAutoAdd.self,
            WeaponCondition.self,
            WeaponCombi.self,
            WeaponMulti.self,
            WeaponNotLoaded.self,
            WeaponRatio.self,
            WeaponSplit.self,
            WeaponSwap.self,
            WeaponUpto.self,
            FavouriteUnit.self
        ]
    }
    static var versionIdentifier: Schema.Version = .init(1, 0, 0)
}

import Foundation
import SwiftData

enum MusterSchemaV2: VersionedSchema {
    static var models: [any PersistentModel.Type] {
        [
            FactionFile.self,
            Categories.self,
            Faction.self,
            GameSystem.self,
            Ally.self,
            Detachment.self,
            Enhancement.self,
            ArmyUnit.self,
            ArmyList.self,
            UnitSize_v2.self,
            UnitComposition.self,
            IncludedUnit.self,
            Models.self,
            Loadout.self,
            BaseLoadout.self,
            Ability.self,
            Equipment.self,
            LoadoutLabel.self,
            AddModels.self,
            AltModels.self,
            Subfaction.self,
            WeaponAdd.self,
            WeaponAutoAdd.self,
            WeaponCondition.self,
            WeaponCombi.self,
            WeaponMulti.self,
            WeaponNotLoaded.self,
            WeaponRatio.self,
            WeaponSplit.self,
            WeaponSwap.self,
            WeaponUpto.self,
            FavouriteUnit.self
        ]
    }
    static var versionIdentifier: Schema.Version = .init(1, 1, 0)
}

I have about 30 classes, each defined in its own file, UnitSize_v1.swift and UnitSize_v2.swift in these cases. I've not copied all the code from these files into the Schema version files like a lot of examples - some of my classes are large and if everything is in one file it'll be enormous.
Here's the code which has the Migration Plan and where the ModelContainer is created
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

// MARK: SwiftData Models
typealias UnitSize = UnitSize_v2

// MARK: Migration Plan
enum MusterMigrationPlan: SchemaMigrationPlan {
    static var schemas: [any VersionedSchema.Type] {
        [
            MusterSchemaV1.self,
            MusterSchemaV2.self
        ]
    }
    
    static var stages: [MigrationStage] {
        [
            migrateV1toV2
        ]
    }
    
    static let migrateV1toV2 = MigrationStage.custom(fromVersion: MusterSchemaV1.self,
                                                     toVersion: MusterSchemaV2.self,
                                                     willMigrate: nil) { context in
        let items = try? context.fetch(FetchDescriptor<UnitSize_v2>())
        items?.forEach { item in
            item.allyCost = 0
        }
        try? context.save()
    }
}

@main
struct MusterPoint_SwiftApp: App {
    var sharedModelContainer: ModelContainer = {
        let schema = Schema([
            FactionFile.self,
            Categories.self,
            Faction.self,
            GameSystem.self,
            Ally.self,
            Detachment.self,
            Enhancement.self,
            ArmyUnit.self,
            ArmyList.self,
            UnitSize.self,
            UnitComposition.self,
            IncludedUnit.self,
            Models.self,
            Loadout.self,
            BaseLoadout.self,
            Ability.self,
            Equipment.self,
            LoadoutLabel.self,
            AddModels.self,
            AltModels.self,
            Subfaction.self,
            WeaponAdd.self,
            WeaponAutoAdd.self,
            WeaponCondition.self,
            WeaponCombi.self,
            WeaponMulti.self,
            WeaponNotLoaded.self,
            WeaponRatio.self,
            WeaponSplit.self,
            WeaponSwap.self,
            WeaponUpto.self,
            FavouriteUnit.self
        ])
        let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)

        do {
            return try ModelContainer(for: schema, 
                                      migrationPlan: MusterMigrationPlan.self,
                                      configurations: [modelConfiguration])
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
        }
    }()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(sharedModelContainer)
    }
}

Running the app I get the following error:
NSLocalizedDescription : Cannot use staged migration with an unknown coordinator model version.

This seems to be because the app can't determine the version of the schema to start with (this is the first migration I've done).
I've tried various combinations of things without moving all the Model code out of the individual files and into the Schema version files - is there another way?

I am no expert on migration but as I see it you have made two changes here, a new property and a modified model name (or added on model and deleted one depending on how you look at it). So how can SwiftData know that UnitSize_v2 is the new UnitSize_v1? Don't you need code to copy all the content in each v1 instance into a new v2 instance rather than just setting one property? I mean the fetch, context.fetch(FetchDescriptor<UnitSize_v2>()), returns zero objects doesn't it?

You can also take a look at this article by Paul Hudson where the changed model instead is part of the VersionedSchema enum and keeps it name between the versions.

Thanks Joakim - that article was one of the ones I used in my first attempt. I don't think it's possible to do what I wanted (avoid having all the code for all classes repeated across multiple schema versions) and I ended up getting it to work by following the article.
